# Razor display the smallest result obtained in a foreach

Tags: razor, foreach, view

it's probably very basic but I can't get my hands on it. In a cshtml view, I would like to return only the smallest number in a foreach.

Example,

```
foreach (PriceDto article in Article.ArticlePrice)
{
article.Price
}
```

which returns all my awards:
450
100
500
990
600
400

I would like to have only the 100. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do it as follows:

```
int min = Article.ArticlePrice.First().Price;
foreach (PriceDto article in Article.ArticlePrice)
{
    if (article.Price < min)
    {
       min = article.Price;
    }
}

// now min has the smallest value, which is 100 in your case
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !